# Django retrieve all comments for a user

Tags: django, django-comments, profiles, django-profiles

I'm using django-profiles and django.contrib.comments and I am trying to display all comments for a particular user in their profile.

This is using the default profile_detail view from django-profiles.

I've tried these two approaches and neither is returning any objects (although objects matching this query do exist):

```
{% for comment in profile.user.comment_set.all %}
```

and

```
{% for comment in profile.user.user_comments.all %}
```

In the source code for django.contrib.comments, the foreign key to user in the Comment model has the following related name:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('user'),
                    blank=True, null=True, related_name="%(class)s_comments")
```

Comments also has a custom manager:

```
# Manager
    objects = CommentManager()
```

Which is defined as:

```
class CommentManager(models.Manager):

    def in_moderation(self):
        """
        QuerySet for all comments currently in the moderation queue.
            """
        return self.get_query_set().filter(is_public=False, is_removed=False)

    def for_model(self, model):
        """
        QuerySet for all comments for a particular model (either an instance or
        a class).
        """
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model)
        qs = self.get_query_set().filter(content_type=ct)
        if isinstance(model, models.Model):
            qs = qs.filter(object_pk=force_unicode(model._get_pk_val()))
        return qs
```

Is the custom manager causing the .all query not to return anything? Am I accessing the reverse relation correctly? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The related name is defined so the default `name_set` will not work. The purpose of `related_name` is to override that default reverse manager name.

```
 user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('user'),
                blank=True, null=True, related_name="%(class)s_comments")
```

So use this:

```
user.comment_comments.all()
```

Comment: thanks. I was using the wrong class name (user instead of comment). Actually it should be: user.comment_comments.all(). The "s" at the end should be switched.